# show query_posts multiple times ( repeat 4 times) wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to show query_posts multiple times ( repeat 4 times) ?

```
        <?php query_posts('showposts=99&cat=4,'); if (have_posts()) : ?>
         <ul id="customCategory" class="group">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
     <li>
     <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()){;?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb');?>
    <?php }?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
   <?php endwhile ;?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking if you can repeat that entire block or code 4 times, or just the `query_posts()` line?

Comment: I want the query_posts()to show the posts 4 times

Comment: I'm a bit confused here.  So you want the same posts to repeat 4 times?

Comment: yes thats right.. the same posts repeated 4 times..

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do that on the same page, but see my answer below.  Just give me a few minutes to write it up.

Comment: This is not a Wordpress issue. There is no reason for query_posts to implement what you can do in a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with wordpress so much, but PHP has a for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++) {
    //insert your code for posting query_posts here one time and it will repeat 4 times.
}
```

A for loop works in the following way;

i=0   -   for i is equal to 0 to start
 i<=3  -   while i is less than or equal to 3 loop through the loop(in your case post    query_posts
 i++   -   add 1 to i, so that it will equal 1 the next iteration, 2 the next iteration, 3 the next, and then it will be equal 3 so the loop will terminate.

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question at all.  The question did not ask anything at all regarding a php for loop.

Comment: @AndyWarren But it did relate. You can simply run a normal PHP loop within _the loop_ to repeat a post 4 times.

Comment: @AndyWarren                                                          I'm not sure how nesting a PHP for loop inside his PHP loops doesn't relate. Considering how PHP is the language he's already using..           Edit: Also this post is in the PHP tag section

Comment: Just because it's tagged PHP doesn't mean his answer is correct or even relevant to the question.  Tossing up and incrementing for loop doesn't even remotely answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

`query_posts()` is used to modify a main loop.  Rather than modifying the main loop, if you want four repeating loops you should use `WP_query`.  Use this loop below, and I guess repeat it four times to get your four sets of posts.

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1,));
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>

    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You can change the word "post" in the first line to get other custom post types also.  Techinically you can use `query_posts` more than once, but you shouldn't.  If you need new queries you should use `WP_query`

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote counter.